# How to Get Custom Properties Common Profile ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, profile

How do I get access to my custom strong-named properties of the common profile (page.profile) in ASP.NET for a classes that does not derive from page? I thought I could just pass in httpcontext.profile but I'm missing the custom properties.

There should be some class type that I can pass in? It appears the class type is ProfileCommon and is auto-generated.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing for others benefit:

```
ProfileCommon common = HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon;
```